# Formatting the result of the length of a line using the 32nd of an inch

Tags: c#, math, formatting, line

I'm measuring the distance between a line.  I believe my math is correct however (as you see from the commenting out of lines) I'm having a hard time getting the results I need. I need a whole number e.g. 5,6,7.  And all of my previous attempts produce incredibly long decimals.

```
private void btnCalc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int dist;
    dist = 0;

    if (p1List.Count != 0 && p2List.Count != 0)
    {

        dist = (Convert.ToInt32(Math.Pow(p1.X - p1.Y, 2) + Math.Pow(p2.X - p2.Y, 2) / 1072));
        //Math.Round(dist, 2);
        //int num = Math.Round(dist, 2);
        //lblLength.Text = dble.ToString("0.0");
        //lblLength.Text = dist.ToString("#.#%");
        //lblLength.Text = String.Format("{0:P1}.", dist);
        //lblLength.Text = string.Format("{0:0.#}");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You must first create a line");
    }
}
```

This probably should be easier than I'm making it.

I'm sorry, I don't usually work on apps like this.

So this dept has a piece of paper that the guys in the shop were drawing little lines on to show issues on a part.  On paper this are very small line, often a fingernail length or less.  Someone was then at the end of the day measuring those lines with a ruler using the '32 scale.  They were then plugging that number into an excel sheet that was doing the math above.

I've since changed the line to `lblLength.Text = (Convert.ToString(dist % 32));`
However it seems odd.  I'm looking at all their past excel sheets and all their lines are 2,3,4,5 nothing much higher than 6.  Yet when I draw a tiny little line in the app the number is 15,18+.  Maybe I shouldn't be measuring `dist` the way that I am?

Comment: If you just output `dist` you'll get a whole number.

Comment: Following your comment on my answer, can you please be clearer as to what you are trying to achieve and what you mean by `whole number` because it doesn't appear as though you mean integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're over complicating this.

All you need to do is `lblLength.Text = dist`.

An `int` is by definition a whole number.

Comment: The number I get, just my most recent attempt only displaying `dist` was like `8123` The way this was being done when they were doing it by hand, was they were measuring to the nearest '32nd of an inch.  So all of there "on paper" calculation were like 4,5,6,7 etc.  And mine is, as mentioned `8123` Is there a way I need to do this, so I get the results they were when they were doing it by hand?  There trying to avoid doing it by hand.

Comment: I think I may have misunderstood you. if you want to get the number of 32ths from a whole inch (assuming that the measurement is calculated in 32ths) you'd do `dist%32`. However, I think you need to edit your question to be more clear as to what you require, then I'll be happy to help you out!

Comment: Your right.  At first I wasn't sure it would matter if it was 32 or not.  Then once I displayed the whole number I figure that may be the reason why I wasn't seeing it the way I needed too.  But this doesn't seem right either.  I added that, and if I make a tiny little line the number is "15" then I make a long line and the number is "18"  That seems weird.  And when they did by hand I never saw anything longer than 8.

Comment: Have you considered that your maths could be wrong? The hardcoded value of 1072 seems suspect. To calculate the distance between 2 points you want something like `Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(x2-x1,2) + Math.Pow(y2-y1,2))`. This is sounding less and less like a formatting issue.

Comment: Well at first it started as formatting issue for me.  But then after correcting my silly mistake it led me to wonder if this is correct.   I removed the `1072` number because actually I didn't need that until later, you  mentioned it jogged my memory thank you.  However even still, I make a tiny little line on the app and its 2,3,4 ok great.  But then if I make a new one the same length its suddenly 18,20,16  I don't get it.